# Using JDBC to connect with AWS Redshift

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, jdbc

I wanted to connect and insert data into my Amazon Redshift table using JDBC. I wrote the following code but keep getting an error at line Class.forName

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Properties;

public class RedShiftDataEmitter {
    static final String redshiftUrl = "jdbc:redshift://xxxxxxxxx:5439/xxxxxx";
    static final String masterUsername = "xxxxxxx";
    static final String password = "xxxxxxx";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Connection connection = null;
        Statement statement = null;

        try {
            Class.forName("com.amazon.redshift.jdbc41.Driver");
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.setProperty("user", masterUsername);
            properties.setProperty("password", password);
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(redshiftUrl, properties);
            // Further code to follow
        } catch(ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
            cnfe.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException sqle) {
            sqle.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Just a heads-up, I can connect to the same cluster using SQL Workbench. My pom.xml is as below

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-redshift -->
  <dependency>
      <groupId>com.amazon.redshift</groupId>
      <artifactId>redshift-jdbc41</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.1.1001</version>
  </dependency>
```

Comment: Is your Driver class on your class path? Whats the exception stack trace?

Comment: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.amazon.redshift.jdbc41.Driver
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
 at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)

Comment: So, how do you run this program? Do you put the driver jar in the *runtime* classpath? (it is not needed when *compiling* the code, since you only use standard JDBC classes).

Comment: I can't find the the maven dependency you posted in Maven central. Are you sure IntelliJ managed to download this dependency? Where did you find it?

Comment: I found the dependency in the aws documentation- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/configure-jdbc-connection-with-maven.html

Comment: Did you add the repository to your pom, as explained in the page you linked to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer, the thing is that Maven does not recognize the redshift dependency. You will have to manually download and add the jar (external jar).

Comment: If the maven doesnt recognize the external dependency you can add the following lines to pom .                                                                                                                      <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>redshift</id>
            <url>http://redshift-maven-repository.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/release</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

Answer (score 12):

1. Add repository first in pom.xml,

```html
<repositories>
  <repository>
      <id>redshift</id>
      <url>http://redshift-maven-repository.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/release</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>
```

2. Now add Amazon redshift Driver jar maven dependeny

```html
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.amazon.redshift</groupId>
  <artifactId>redshift-jdbc42</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.1.1001</version>
</dependency>
```

Use this driver **com.amazon.redshift.jdbc42.Driver**

**Clean** and **build** the project, it should work now.